# Simulate an resizable() action with an custom handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to apply the same element of re-sizing to an element with my own action handlers? Lets look at the code.

This is my regular resizable handler, any element with the class `.resizable` will be resizable with the provided param's (`animate,grid,zIndex`).

```
$('.resizable').resizable({
    animate: true,
    grid: [$(this).width(),$(this).height()],
    zIndex: 0
});
```

Now my custom event. I want it to simulate the above as the mouse moves. Comment explain it further.

```
$("#main").on('mousedown', function(e){

    // Create an new image element
    // and append it to the #danka div
    // and apply an mousemove event.

    appendTo('#danka').on("mousemove", function(e){

           // I need it so; as the mouse moves, 
           // it simulate the .resizable() event,
           // created above with all param.

    });

});
```

Basically I trying to take the mouse move (track mouse position) and pass it to the .resizable() event to take care of the actual re-sizing.

Is this possible? I looked at `trigger()` but can't seem to see how it would work?
 
Thanks.

Comment: You would like to resize an element when another, with the same class, is resized?

Comment: @AlessandroGabrielli No. Re-size an element as the mouse moves (track mouse position) and simulate as if it was a resizable() element.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/CbYtT/3/